# ROC / AUC for polynomial Labels

Tags: classification, roc, auc, rapidminer

How can I calculate the Area Under Curve for a classifier of a polynomial label in Rapidminer? I could only find a performance operator for binomial labels that provides the AUC value.

Comment: Do you mean multinomial?

Comment: is it must be Rapidminer? asking a specific software is usually not a topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Receiver Operating Characteristic curves and associated Area Under Curve measures work with binary classifiers. There is more complexity when multiple values for the labels are possible (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_curve) link)

I believe the R package `PerfMeas` supports this so you could take advantage of the RapidMiner R extension to get access to this.